# C++ anonymous string destruction time

Tags: c++, string

We have a function `GetString()` that returns a `std::string`.  We then have a function `ConsumeString(char*)` that consumes a C-style string.

Is it a bug to write `ConsumeString(GetString().c_str())`?  To me it looks like this would be a bug because after `c_str()` runs, the original anonymous string will get destructed and you'll have a pointer to something that doesn't exist anymore.  But weirdly, it always seems to work fine.

I only noticed it could be an issue when I tried to assign `GetString().c_str()` to a variable and then use it in two separate `ConsumeString()` functions, at which point it printed a corrupted string and the problem became obvious.  But I don't know why it seems to work in the former case.

Is it potentially a bug that just happens to work, or does C++ specifically allow this?

Comment: The linked question does not answer this question; here it is about the lifetime of a temporary object, there it is about the lifetime of the C string. The linked question answers that the lifetime of the C string is linked to the lifetime of the string; here we want to know how long that string lives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless ConsumeString does some asynchronous processing of `const char*` provided to it (directly or indirectly) this code is very safe.

A temporary returned by `GetString()` will be alive until the function `ConsumeString` returns, so if it is done all it's business with it's argument before returning, everything will work correctly.

In your other scenario - I assume, you had something like this:

```
 const char* s = GetString().c_str(); // 1
 ConsumeString(s); // 2
```

temporary returned by `GetString` was destroyed after line 1 ended, so `ConsumeString` consumed an invalid pointer.

For a bit more formal wording regarding lifetime of temporary object, one might consult [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime), in particular

> All temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the
> full-expression that (lexically) contains the point where they were
> created, and if multiple temporary objects were created, they are
> destroyed in the order opposite to the order of creation.

Comment: "A temporary returned by GetString() will be alive until the function ConsumeString returns" Your answer would be perfect if you add a reference for that statement.

Comment: @DanielJour, sure